# Select option with jquery based on other select option box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 select boxes. I want to manipulate the other box based on the option selected in the first box.

```
<select name="abc" id="abc">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

And second select box

```
<select name="xyz" id="xyz">
  <option value="1">X</option>
  <option value="2">Y</option>
  <option value="3">Z</option>
</select>
<br>
```

Now what I want is, when the page loads, if I select option 1 i.e A, the second check box should automatically be set to option 3 i.e Z and vice versa. If I select option 2 i.e B in first selectbox, second select box should display option 1 i.e X and vice versa, and so on. What jquery function to use?

Comment: Why can't you use "selected" attribute to select the default text ? After that you can write `change` listener on select field to achieve what you need

Comment: is there any rule for selection of options from both select box ?

Comment: Try to use: http://jsfiddle.net/x2y7hwsy/1/

Comment: thanks @QArea worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do simply something like this, using **[`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** event handler

```js
var $select = $('#abc,#xyz');
$select.change(function() {
  $select.val(this.value);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="abc" id="abc">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
<select name="xyz" id="xyz">
  <option value="2">X</option>
  <option value="3">Y</option>
  <option value="1">Z</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you. but it is selecting similar value element. If I select A I want Z not X. How to do that. For B = X and for C =Y

Comment: oh sorry i will fix it

Comment: can i change the value

Comment: @VivekPadhye : check it now

Comment: thanks for this trick. I could not understand what u meant by changing value, but now I got it. But just for my info, is there other way without this trick(changing values to match)? like if else statement or something like that?

Comment: Can you just show it with first 2 options? I will do the rest. I have many options though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74920/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-vivek-padhye).